# I can't get my php to add all the things I need for it to add

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to add the if statements to the `$totalReimb` as well as the `$totalMileReimb` but can't seem to be able to get them to add only the `$totalMileReimb` is added

The variables

```
    $ratePerMile = 0.35;
    $miles = $_POST['miles'];
    $bfast = $_POST['bfast'];
    $lunch = $_POST['lunch'];
    $dinner = $_POST['dinner'];
    $hotel = $_POST['hotel'];
    $totalMileReimb = $miles * $ratePerMile;
    $totalReimb = 0 + $totalMileReimb;
    $Yes = "Yes";
    $No = "No";
```

The If Statements

```
    if ($miles < 1 or $miles > 3000){
        // input error message
        print ("<p> Input Error, Try Again! </p>");
        // link back to the form
        print ("<a href=\"juarez-biz-travel.html\">Return to form</a>");
    } else {
        if ($miles >=10 or $miles <= 3000 );{
            if ($bfast == $Yes) $totalReimb + 8.50;
            if ($lunch == $Yes) $totalReimb + 12.50;
            if ($dinner == $Yes)$totalReimb + 18.50;
            if ($hotel == $Yes) $totalReimb +  110.00;
        }
        print ("<p> The Total Is $$totalReimb! </p>");
    }
```

Comment: The miles are received through the HTML in the input method

Comment: The If statements the $bfast and other variables are received from the HTML also but, they are through selective response

Comment: There's a `;` behind `if ($miles >=10 or $miles <= 3000 )` I don't think that's supposed to be there since you're trying to do something based on that if statement

Comment: Mark, if I remove the ; I receive an undefined variable notice

Comment: Actually no I don't error from my end

Comment: I think you might have a problem with `$$totalReimb` as well, as for `$totalReimb == 50` it will try to look for `$50` which is wrong and not display anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error is this, `$totalReimb + 12.50` should be one of the following:

- `$totalReimb = $totalReimb + 12.50`
- `$totalReimb += 12.50`.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks, That Did The Trick

Comment: I think OP might also have a problem with $$totalReimb as well, as for $totalReimb == 50 it will try to look for $50 which is wrong and not display anything